# Asynchronously wait until there is a connection

Tags: python-3.x

```
def waiting():
    while True:
        for i in range(3):
            print("Waiting")
            time.sleep(1)
            os.system('cls')
            print("Waiting.")
            time.sleep(1)
            os.system('cls')
            print("Waiting..")
            time.sleep(1)
            os.system('cls')
            print("Waiting...")
            time.sleep(1)
            os.system('cls')
```

```
def succesful_connect():
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 5000  
    your_host = socket.gethostname()
    your_host=socket.gethostbyname(your_host)
    print('Your IP:', your_host)
    server_socket = socket.socket()  
    server_socket.bind((host, port))  
    server_socket.listen(2)
    conn, address = server_socket.accept()  
    return conn, address
```

The problem is that the line of code ` conn, address = server_socket.accept() ` completely slows down the program and it is impossible to do anything until there is a connection

I think it's possible to use the asynchronous library, but I can't figure out how to use it to make `waiting()` spin a waiting loop until there is a connection in a successful connection

- Windows 11
- Python 3.11.3

At first I tried to make a wait loop until the connection, but the loop can't be stopped then

Comment: In the socket library there is a line of code server_socket_accept(), which is waiting for a connection and completely slows down the program. I want to make while this line of code works (i.e. searching for a connection), the waiting function is running

Comment: Put that in your question then.